# Automatizing the questions and answers asked in Dialogflow from a json file that contains them

Tags: javascript, json, dialogflow-es

I have a DialogFlow chatbot where I create question and answer cards. I write them by hand. However, I have this list as a question in a json file. How can I access the questions and answers in my file instead of writing them by hand? Is there a way to bulk download or access the questions and answer used by the Dialogflow agent?

Here is the online editor code for my chatbot

```
'use strict';

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const {WebhookClient} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
const {Card, Suggestion, Payload} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
var answers = [];
var score = {};


process.env.DEBUG = 'dialogflow:debug'; // enables lib debugging statements

exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });

  function answerIntroductionHandler(agent){
    agent.add(new Card({
        title: '1 Faut-il accélérer l’automatisation du métro ?', # pregunta 1
        imageUrl: 'http://www.leparisien.fr/resizer/mz-PnB5RECZ1q-z9GDRvlB_3jsg=/932x582/arc-anglerfish-eu-central-1-prod-leparisien.s3.amazonaws.com/public/RJPSM346RO4M5VIDDOS35APBII.jpg'
      })
    );
    agent.add(new Suggestion("Oui"));
    agent.add(new Suggestion("Non"));
  }

  function answer1Handler(agent){

    const answer = agent.parameters.Boolean;

    if(answer === 'true'){
      score.griveaux = (score.griveaux+1) || 1 ;
    }else{
    }

    answers.push(answer);

    agent.add(new Card({
        title: '2 Faut-il faire payer le stationnement des deux-roues ?', # pregunta 2
        imageUrl: 'https://img.autoplus.fr/news/2017/06/28/1517769/c4d017960fb061c5e50cf2c4-1350-900.jpg?r'
      })
    );
    agent.add(new Suggestion("Oui"));
    agent.add(new Suggestion("Non"));

  }

  function answer2Handler(agent){
    const answer = agent.parameters.Boolean;
    answers.push(answer);

    if(answer === 'true'){
      score.villani = (score.villani+1) || 1;
    }else{
    }
    console.log(score);

    var max = Object.keys(score).reduce(function(a, b){ return score[a] > score[b] ? a : b ;});
    agent.add('Vous semblez etre assez proche de ' + max);

  }

  function answer3Handler(agent){
    console.log(agent.parameters);
    const answer = agent.parameters.Boolean;
    answers.push(answer);

    if(answer === 'true'){
      score.villani = (score.villani+1) || 1;
    }else{
    }
    console.log(score);

    var max = Object.keys(score).reduce(function(a, b){ return score[a] > score[b] ? a : b ;});
    agent.add('Vous semblez etre assez proche de ' + max);
  }


  // Run the proper function handler based on the matched Dialogflow intent name
  let intentMap = new Map();
  intentMap.set('answerIntroduction', answerIntroductionHandler);
  intentMap.set('answer1', answer1Handler);
  intentMap.set('answer2', answer2Handler);

  agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
});
```

Here's my json file of questions and answers:

```
{
    "Transports": {
        "Faut-il accélérer l’automatisation du métro ?": [
            "Oui",
            "Non"
        ],
        "Faut-il faire payer le stationnement des deux-roues ?": [
            "Oui",
            "Non"
        ],
        "Faut-il interdire les bus de tourisme dans la capitale ?": [
            "Oui",
            "Non"
        ],
        "Faut-il piétonniser les quatre arrondissements centraux de la capitale ?": [
            "Oui",
            "Non"
        ],
        "Faut-il réduire le nombre de places de stationnement en surface ?": [
            "Oui",
            "Non"
        ],
        "Faut-il rendre le Vélib' gratuit ?": [
            "Oui",
            "Non"
        ],
        "Faut-il renforcer la vidéoverbalisation ?": [
            "Oui",
            "Non"
        ],
        "Faut-il rouvrir à la circulation les voies sur berges ?": [
            "Oui",
            "Non"
        ],
        "Faut-il interdire les trottinettes électriques ? (free floating)": [
            "Oui",
            "Non"
        ],
        "Le périphérique doit-il...": [
            "... être supprimé",
            "... comprendre une voie pour bus et covoiturage",
            "... être préservé"
        ],
        "Les transports doivent-ils être rendus gratuits...": [
            "... uniquement pour les seniors",
            "... pour les mineurs et les seniors",
            "... pour tout le monde",
            "Non, ils doivent rester payants"
        ]
    },
    "Sports et Loisirs": {
        "Faut-il demander l'annulation des Jeux olympiques ?": [
            "Oui",
            "Non"
        ],
        "Faut-il mettre fin à la pratique du tirage au sort pour le conservatoire ?": [
            "Oui",
            "Non"
        ]
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you put them in CSV format, you can use [Knowledge Connectors](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/knowledge-connectors) for this.